# Add data to line chart js dynamically with multiple lines

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, chart.js

I need to show an array of n lines on my line chart in Angular 5.

I created my line chart like this on my component:

```
lineRecoveriesChartData: any[] = [    {data: this.arrayOfResult, label: '', borderColor: "black", fill: false}  ];
```

after I received my data from the server post I try to load them with something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        this.lineResult = arrayOfIntegerReceivedFromServer[i];
        this.lineRecoveriesChartData.push(
            this.lineResult
        );
    }
```

this is not the only thing I tried of course... I tried to make use of datasets, I tried to set a timeout, I tried to use the update function of my chart...
But it always fail to update my data on the chart.

I know for a fact that something more static like this:

```
lineRecoveriesChartData: any[] = [    {data: this.arrayFromServer, label: '', borderColor: "black", fill: false},  {data: this.array2FromServer, label: '', borderColor: "black", fill: false} ];
```

works, but I need to generate multiple lines and I don't know how many of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the secret is to don't put any data in the initial array and use ngif until there is data on the array of data.